# Required atributte in EF MVC4 dropdownList Fail

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

Im creating a MVC4 application with EF, I have two simple classes, Brand and CarModel, Brand have a Name (Required) and CarModel have a Brand (Required). The problem is that im getting an error on the ModelState.IsValid because with the dropdown to select a Brand it only fills in the Brand ID.

How can i make leave the required in Brand Name but be able to use the dropdown in CarModel? Here is my code:

```
    public class Brand
    {


        public int Id { get; set; } 
        [Required]       
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Logo { get; set; }

    }

    public class CarModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Brand Brand{ get; set; }
    }
```

I have the full Crud for Brand working ok. But im triying to do it for CarModel, here is what i have in the controller for create Brand:

```
 public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.BrandSelect = new SelectList(myRepository.GetBrands.ToList(), "Id", "Name");
            return View();
        }

  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Crear(CarModel carModel )
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {



                myrepository.Create(Modelo);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }


            return View(carModel );
        }
```

And in the view

```
<div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Brand)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">

            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Brand.Id,ViewBag.BrandSelect as SelectList)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Brand)
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I understand you properly, your CarModel class should have a BrandId (int) and a Brand object.

```
public class CarModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int BrandId { get; set; }


    public Brand Brand{ get; set; }
}
```

Your DropDownList should be bound to the BrandId

```
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BrandId, ViewBag.BrandSelect as SelectList)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Brand)
```

[more EF code First Paren-Child](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/01/23/associations-in-ef-code-first-ctp5-part-3-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations.aspx)

Comment: Thanks i tried this and its working, this should be enough for now.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think the `[Required]` attribute on `BrandId` makes any difference. Since `BrandId` is `int`, a non-nullable type, it will always have a value, so making it required is redundant. To make it optional you would need to use `int?`.

Comment: I'd be curious to know if the validation message for the combo box ever shows now that you've made this change.

Comment: that's technically true. a non-nullable field will be treated as required. better form to have it, but not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You have a pre-populated items in `BrandSelect` and that means that `Brand.Id` is guaranteed to be existing in the database. Also, you are not creating a `Brand` when you are creating a `CarModel`. So,  you can have a view model instead that represents your `CarModel` and return it to your view, that's best practice. Consider this:

**Your Model**

```
public class CarFormModel // this is a "model class" and not your entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int BrandId { get; set; }
    //replacement for your ViewBag.BrandSelect
    //you can also create a viewmodel for this
    //but let's use your entity for a more simple example
    public IEnumerable<Brand> Brands {get;set;}
}
```

**Your Controller, for GET method**

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var model = new CarFormModel {
        Brands = get_brands_from_database(),
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

**Your View**

```
@model CarFormModel
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextboxFor(model => model.Name) // capture the name of the car model
<div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BrandId, new SelectList(Model.Brands,  "Id", "Name", Model.BrandId)) // capture the brand for the car model
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BrandId)
</div>
```

**Your Controller, for POST method**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CarFormModel carModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        // map the model back to entity or pass it to your service that creates the model
        myrepository.Create(the_mapped_or_created_carmodel_entity);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(carModel);
}
```

This option is better than what you have now in that you are not using a ViewBag for your dropdown and you are not exposing a proxy object on your view. A good practice is to always use a view model on your view.

Comment: Thanks I see this should be how i do it